# How to solve TimeoutException: com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, timeoutexception

I saw this issue in my bug report:

```
   Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.isRunning(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:219)
   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The bug only occurs in Android 8 devices. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: did you got your answer ? I'm facing the same issue